# Flexslider - Remove next and prev navigation elements in the main image

Tags: flexslider

Is there an option for Flexslider to remove the next and previous navigation elements in the main image?

I just want to remove them and let the bottom carousel navigation handle it exclusively.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, after fumbling around myself to disable the arrows, I figured out this section of js controls it:

// Primary Controls

controlNav: true,               //Boolean: Create navigation for paging control of each clide? Note: Leave true for manualControls usage

directionNav: false,             //Boolean: Create navigation for previous/next navigation? (true/false)

directionNav is the previous/next navigations- setting it as false rather than the default true eliminates the arrows (and the "previous/next" you get if you remove the arrows)

Hope that helps!